# Why ltrace doesn't show a call to glibc __nss_configure_lookup()

Tags: debugging, glibc, ltrace

I'm trying to understand how `ltrace` command works.

So I've been poking around in [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html). I have a "hosts: resolve" line in there - it tells **glibc** to dynamically load [`nss-resolve`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libnss-resolve/nss-resolve.8.en.html) plugin module when doing hostname lookup. I was hoping to see the plugin being loaded with `ltrace`:

```
$ ltrace getent hosts google.com
mtrace()                                                           = <void>
setlocale(LC_ALL, "")                                              = "en_GB.UTF-8"
textdomain("libc")                                                 = "libc"
argp_parse(0x55e7c8bf5140, 3, 0x7fffd79d00c8, 0)                   = 0
strcmp("hosts", "hosts")                                           = 0
inet_pton(10, 0x7fffd79d11fb, 0x7fffd79cff60, 0)                   = 0
inet_pton(2, 0x7fffd79d11fb, 0x7fffd79cff60, 38)                   = 0
gethostbyname2(0x7fffd79d11fb, 10, 0, 55)                          = 0x7fbb0311b340
inet_ntop(10, 0x55e7c8f3ba38, 0x7fffd79cfef0, 46)                  = 0x7fffd79cfef0
printf("%-15s %s", "2a00:1450:4009:", "google.com")                = 35
__overflow(0x7fbb03118760, 10, 0x7fffd79cf990, 02a00:1450:4009:816::200e google.com) = 10
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

There is nothing in the output of `ltrace` that looks like plugin being loaded, although I could confirm that `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_resolve.so.2` is indeed loaded using `strace`.

For example I'm 99% sure the loading process involves [a call](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/getent.c;h=897f4454ff54e769f01106b8e5f24e83ca520cb3;hb=HEAD#l890) to [`__nss_configure_lookup()` from glibc/nss/nsswitch.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nsswitch.c;h=8d7b69d4bc63677dc9cacdbec6fb85ff70fb6221;hb=HEAD#l256) but there is no such call is in the output - why? Is there a way to see `__nss_configure_lookup()` being called using `ltrace` or some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

> `$ ltrace getent hosts google.com`

> For example I'm 99% sure the loading process involves a call to __nss_configure_lookup() from glibc/nss/nsswitch.c

Why should that be? You're not using the `-s` flag [1]:

```
% ltrace getent -s hosts:dns hosts google.com
...
__nss_configure_lookup(0x563d2eecc194, 0x7ffcff9ec80f, 5, 9) = 0
...
```

> There is nothing in the output of ltrace that looks like plugin being loaded,

`ltrace` is not able to trace any call internal to a library. With a debugger like `gdb` you may set breakpoints and watchpoints wherever you like.

---

[1] quoting from the source you link to:

```
 879 static error_t
 880 parse_option (int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state)
 881 {
 882   char *endp;
 883   switch (key)
 884     {
 885     case 's':
 886       endp = strchr (arg, ':');
 887       if (endp == NULL)
 888         /* No specific database, change them all.  */
 889         for (int i = 0; databases[i].name != NULL; ++i)
 890           __nss_configure_lookup (databases[i].name, arg);
 891       else
 892         {
 893           int i;
 894           for (i = 0; databases[i].name != NULL; ++i)
 895             if (strncmp (databases[i].name, arg, endp - arg) == 0)
 896               {
 897                 __nss_configure_lookup (databases[i].name, endp + 1);
 898                 break;
 899               }
 900           if (databases[i].name == NULL)
 901             error (EXIT_FAILURE, 0, gettext ("Unknown database name"));
 902         }
 903       break;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I completely missed `case 's'` there! I'm back to being mystified as to how and when glibc loads libnss_* plugins.

Comment: `nss_load_library` -> ... -> `_dl_open`; the same way dlopen() does it.